# Archer GRC calculation based on percentage

Tags: archer, rsa-archer-grc

I have two numeric type fields to base a calculation on. I want the third field type to display the correct percent, which I want resulting in 20% (1/5):

```
([Number Comments Adopted]/(COUNT([Number Comments Submitted])))
```

Current result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following calculation formalar should work for "Percent Adopted" field:

```
100*[Number Comments Adopted]/[Number Comments Submitted]
```

Field "Percent Adopted" has property "Suffix" set to "%" and property "Decimal Places" set to "2".

Tested examples:

[image]
[image]

Good luck!